# How to divide matrix elements by corresponding matrix row sum in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

For example,

```
M= [[1,2], [7,8]]
```

then I want

```
[[1/3, 2/3], [7/15, 8/15]]
```

I'm trying to do this vectorized. One idea I have is to write `s = np.sum(M, axis=1)`; this gives us the corresponding row sums. Then I could maybe transpose `s`, and copy it along the columns, then do an elementwise division of `M/s`, but even this seems too hacky. What's the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`tile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) to repeat it along the dimension on which `sum` operated.

```
M / np.tile(np.sum(M, 1), (1, M.shape[1]))
```